# Toggle Buttons not getting passed in Toggle Group(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, toggle

I am stuck in an issue which is little bit confusing. I am using toggle button under an empty game object consisting toggle group script. When I am placing this group under a panel in Canvas, the programming is running properly, but when I create a full form style type panels and groups, the toggle group shows that there is no toggle under toggle group. I have checked for all the assigning and sample running part but the issue still persists. Maybe I am doing some silly mistakes, but I am not sure what is it.

For getting the active toggle, I have watched [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXeGLwPMmR8&t=163s) and coded like this

```
    ToggleGroup toggleGroup;

    private void Start()
    {
        toggleGroup = GetComponent<ToggleGroup>();
    }

    string val;
    Toggle toggle;
    public string ToggleData()
    {
        toggle = toggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();

        if (toggle == null)
            val = "No";
        else if (toggle != null)
            val = toggle.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
        return val;
    }
```

I have added an image of the hierarchy
[image: This is hierarchy image]

[[image: This is the toggle component's inspector image1]

Comment: why doing `toggleGroup = GetComponent<ToggleGroup>();` every frame in `Update`? Do you have configured your `ToggleGroup` in all your `Toggle` components? Having them only as children of it is not enough

Comment: About the `ToggleGroup = GetComponent<ToggleGroup>();`, it will be in the `Start` method, I forgot to edit that part and will edit it in the question now. And about configuring, do you mean assigning the `ToggleGroup` to the `Toggle` component?

Comment: Yes exactly .. nesting them under the `ToggleGroup` doesn't do anything .. you also have to assign the `ToggleGroup` o all your `Toggle`'s `group` property/field via the Inspector - it's kinda poorly documented but see the description of [ToggleGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ToggleGroup.html) `The Toggle Group is setup by dragging the Toggle Group object to the Group property of each of the Toggles in the group.` Triple check whether you have the correct one

Comment: Yes I have done that too. The toggle group is working well if I put the whole panel outside **Background** named panel, neither I changed the code nor the inspector settings but when I put it in the way as shown in the hierarchy image, no value is passed in the `ToggleGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

I have reassigned the ToggleGroup in each Toggle UI, then it started to work.